# text-rendering: optimizeLegibility crashes Android stock browser

Tags: android, css, text-rendering

Today I noticed that *all* of my webpages crash the stock browser on my HTC. After some debugging I found that `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;` causes this. After removing it from my code everything worked alright.
Can somebody confirm this? Is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with text-rendering on Nexus 7, using a WebView (which basically is the stock browser).
It didn't crash anything, but it ignored all font-family declarations in the CSS. It just used the default font on everything.