# Property text-rendering doesn't exist : optimizelegibility

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css

Using this code at web browsers:

```
.h1,.h2,.h3,.h4,.h5,.h6{margin:1.25em 0 0.2em;text-rendering:optimizeLegibility}
```

On WC3 validation Getting error

> Property text-rendering doesn't exist : optimizelegibility

and seems this property having some issue for android as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179681/text-rendering-optimizelegibility-crashes-android-stock-browser)

Is the property no longer exists now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It never existed; `text-rendering` is part of SVG, not CSS.

> The text-rendering property is an SVG property that is not defined in
>   any CSS standard. However, Gecko and WebKit browsers let you apply
>   this property to HTML and XML content on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.

In other words, that `text-rendering` has an effect on non-SVG elements at all is nonstandard. According to the MDN page, it's not widely supported anyway (Internet Explorer and Opera don't understand it) and the implementations that do exist have known issues.

It might be best to avoid it altogether.

Source: [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-rendering).

Comment: How we can combinely used svg with css3 in the above format, is there any declaration/ linking required?